# Cocoa Touch UITableView Data

Tags: objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch

I am working for the first time in objective c and have come across an issue that I have not seen an answer for.

I am loading a set of data from a JSON data set and using it to populate a UITableView within a UITableViewController.

First when the view is loaded (viewDidLoad) I populate the array with the JSON data from a URL.

Next the data loads as it should. numberOfRowsInSection shows that there are 30 results in the array which is correct.

However The Iphone loads the entire set three times into the tableview.

Here is some code from the controller for that view:(Twitter is being used as an example and is not the actual data set I use)

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
 //results = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

 self.navigationItem.title=@"public_timeline";
 self.tableView.allowsSelection = NO;
 NSString *url = [[NSString alloc] init];
 url = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"http://twitter.com/statuses/%s.json",@"public_timeline"];
 if ([results count] == 0) {
  [self parseJSON:url];
 }
    }

Here is the parseJSON (actual parse is done with the Cocoa JSON framework

    -(void) parseJSON:(NSString *)URL{
     NSURL *JSONURL = [NSURL URLWithString:URL];
     NSData *responseData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:JSONURL];
     NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
     results = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[responseString JSONValue]];
    }


    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
     return [results count];
    }
```

then the cell's output

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
  // Set up the cell...
    }
    NSDictionary *cdict = [results objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; 
 cell.textLabel.text = [cdict valueForKey:@"text"];
    return cell;
}
```

I am not sure if what I am doing is the best way to do this, so if someone could help me out that would be great.

Comment: By "loading three times" do you mean you're getting 3 copies of each table view cell in your table view? Or, are you witnessing your breakpoint get hit 3 times before your table loads?

Comment: 3 Copies of the data are showing up in the view cells.

Answer (score 0):

Check the `numberOfSectionsInTableView` Method and change the return Value to 1

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
   return 1;
}
```